# android :How to change color of text of counter app after ( 33,66,99,elc ) clicks?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, for-loop, if-statement

**How to change counter when is 33,66,99,elc ??**

the project is here on githup https://github.com/hamza94max/Counter

any one can help me ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView=findViewById(R.id.countertext);
        reset=findViewById(R.id.reset);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=findViewById(R.id.reltivee);



        relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;


                    textView.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


                }
        });


    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a reminder **%** like that && add funcation for random color.

```
  relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
               if (counter % 33 == 0) textView.setTextColor(getRandomColor);

                    textView.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                }
        });

    private int getRandomcolor() {
        int[] colors = {Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW}; // Add colors you want 
        int random = new Random().nextInt(colors.length);
        return colors[random];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change color by using modulo like that

```
int currentColor = Color.BLACK;//this is activity level variable


if(counter%33 == 0){
    currentColor = getRandomColor()//implement getRandomColor() method
}
textView.setTextColor(currentColor)
```

Comment: I tried before but it changes only color of number 33 and I need change color between 33 and 66 ,66 and 99 ...elc

Comment: Actually this would change the color at 33, 66, 99 and all other multiples of 33.

Comment: I want to change color every 33 times from random colors , I know how to make a random but I want the condition or for loop

Comment: please look the last version of my answer I think it is correct. Every multiple of 33 you change the color of the text than you use this color until the counter's value hits to another multiple of 33

Comment: Yes , it is very useful

Comment: @Hamza Khalifa Why do you want him to vote on your question? This is not how stack overflow works. Your question doesn't need more attention. Your question needs more details. No one really knows what you want to achieve. We gave you three options but none seem to be what you are looking for. If you can't explain what the code should do, maybe you can explain more about the context of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
if (counter>=33 && counter<66){
  //counter is bigger or equal than 33 AND smaller than 66
  //33, 34, ... 64, 65
  textView.setTextColor(color)
} else if (counter>=66 && counter<99) {
  textView.setTextColor(color)
} else if (counter>=99) {
  textView.setTextColor(color)
}
```

Comment: but I want every 33 times ?

Comment: If you want 33,66,99,... than @M.ekici 's answer is correct. Give us some examples.

Comment: @M.ekici solution change the only numbers 33,66,99 elc

Comment: I want to change color every 33 times from random colors , I know how to make a random but I want the condition or for loop

Comment: Do u know how ?